# how to test Hadoop mapreduce

Tags: testing, hadoop, mapreduce

How can I test a Hadoop mapreduce application generally before it's ready for production. The testing perspectives that I can think of for now are:

- Unit test

  This is to make sure the methods in mappers and reducers are working correctly. It seems we already have [mrunit](https://mrunit.apache.org/), but I'd like to see if we have any other options.
- Data accuracy

  This is the most important to me because producing the accurate and correct output is the main responsibility of a mapreduce application. The question here is how to generate test data set and how to verify the output data, and what is the proper test data amount?
- Performance

  How should we benchmark and test performance of a mapreduce application? Any tools we can leverage?

Any other tests we need to consider as well?